# Leaking Fragments from FragmentManager

Tags: android, memory-leaks, fragment, fragmentmanager

I'm struggling with a Fragment leak and I am not sure how to handle it:

I have a FragmentActivity(I'm using support lib v4) with two buttons: forth and back. Forth button adds a fragment to the backstack with a long animation and back button pops the fragment from the backstack.

Code for forth button click listener:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.own_slide_in_left, R.anim.own_slide_out_right, R.anim.own_slide_in_left, R.anim.own_slide_out_right);
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_holder, new FirstFragment());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

And for back button click listener:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

When I press the back button and rotate the device while the animation is ongoing then after rotation visually everything seems to be ok, but the previous Fragment is leaked. I can tell it by having a breakpoint in, for example, Fragment's ctor or onSaveInstanceState(). It will be it on each rotation when it shouldn't be.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This problem persists using native Fragments, Android 4.0.3

Comment: With leaked what do you mean? Fragments are not destroyed as activities after being detached...That's why you can assign a TAG to a fragment and attach it again later on.

Comment: My fragment holds a lot of resources and doing it a several times causes out of memory error, because each time Fragment is created and 'leaked' when rotating. How should I fix it to completely remove them?

Comment: Are you sure you are reusing the same fragment or are you recreating a new one every time? Another thing, in onDetach callback nullify instance variable like View (every variable that is declared as class variable and that has a reference to the context).

Comment: I am creating a new one every time, but I can't understand why this problem persists only if the screen orientation occurs while the animation is not finished yet. If the animation is finished and then I rotate the device then everything is OK.

Comment: I suggest you to reuse the same recovering it using its tag

Comment: It won't help, because after rotation each Fragment object is created by FragmentManager.restoreAllState. And because the fragment was incorrectly saved in FragmentManager.saveAllState() I will still have leaked fragments.